# Copy Constructor of Base class should not be called

Tags: c++, templates

This is just a code snippet explaining the class hierarchy, not the actual problematic code

```
class A
{};

class B : public class C
{};

class C : public NocopyClass // constructors are private in Nocopy class
{};

template<typename T1, typename T2>
class D
public:
  T1 _t1;
  T2 _t2;
  D(T1& t1, T2& t2) : _t1(t1),_t2(t2) {}

{
};

class E: public class D<A,B>
{
    E(const& a,const& b) : D<A,B>(a,b) {}
};
```

calling function:

```
A objA;
B objB;

E objE(objA,objB);
```

From the calling program I want to pass A's object and B's object to class E
Here the copy constructor defined in E gets called and the objects of A and B are copied which in turn in invoking the copy constructor of class B, till the super base class NocopyClass copy constructor, which does not allow the objects to get copied.

How do i modify the calling function such that the base class constructors are not called?
Is there any way?

Comment: Circumventing the baseclass copy constructor is impossible and unwanted. What use would a uninitialised base class be? There is likely a good reason for those classes to be non-copyable...

Comment: Can you provide *actual* code? `E(const& a, const& b)` is not a thing. And nowhere here is `E`'s copy constructor called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try declaring _t1 and _t2 as references.

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
{
class D
public:
  T1 &_t1;
  T2 &_t2;
  D(T1& t1, T2& t2) : _t1(t1),_t2(t2) {}


};
```

Comment: Alternate implementation. Change T1 _t1 and _t2 to pointers. You can copy pointers without calling copy constructors.

Answer (score 0):

You could *move* the instance of `B` instead of copying it, but you would not be able to do it exactly the way you want - You cannot pass an already existing instance of `B`, you need to send a new one to `E` (see the code of `main` bellow):

```
#include <utility>  

template<typename T1, typename T2>
class D
public:
  T1 _t1;
  T2 _t2;
  D(T1 &t1, T2 &&t2) : _t1 (t1) {
      _t2 = std::move (t2) ;
  }
};

class E: public class D<A,B>
{
    E(const& a, &&b) : D<A,B>(a, std::move(b)) {}
};
```

And when creating a new instance of `E`, you would need to do it this way:

```
A a; // no problem with a
E (a, B()) ; // You need to have a rvalue for b
```

See [std::move](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) documentation - There are lots of topics on SO about move and rvalue reference.